# No match for operator []

Tags: c++

why is this code giving me an error?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
string k;
vector<string> f;
int main()

{
    string k;
    while (cin >> k) {
        char l = '3';
        cin >> k;
        for (auto &v : k) {
            if (v == 'e')
                v = l;
            if (v == 'i')
                v = '1';
            if ( v == 'z')
                v = '2';
        }

        f.push_back(k);
    }
    auto r = f.begin();
    auto s = f.end();
    while (r != s) { 
        string j = f[r];
        cout << j;
        ++r;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile it and edit it many times, but I always get this error.
So I tried to use different types for iterators but that could not be done eighter.
Does anyone have a suggestion to solve this?
It would be a leet text generator

Comment: you dont acces an element via `f[r]` when `r` is an iterator. To dereference it use `*r` instead

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to mix two different ways to access an element in an `std::vector`, using an iterator and using the subscript operator.

If you want to use the subscript operator, you have to call it with a valid index into the vector, e.g.:

```
std::string s = v[1]; // get the second element of the vector
```

If you want to use iterators, you would do it like this instead:

```
auto it = v.begin();
std::string s = *it; // get the element referred by the iterator it
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `r` is an iterator, you use it like a pointer, not like an array index. So `f[r]` should be `*r`.

```
string j = *r;
```